# Access VBA Comparing Table Values to Constant And Updating It

Tags: database, vba, compare

Ok so I'm trying to writing VBA code to automate as much as possible.  What I need it to do is read from a field in a table and if it meets the conditions than it copy that to a new table.  It's for rotation purposes.  If `CurrentDate` equals `NextDateOut` than whatever value of that item I want to go to a certain table but also want to update values in the current table.  `NextDateOut` will be the new `LastDateOut` value in the table and `NextDateIn` will be 10 days from NextDateIn and `NextDateOut` will be 10 days from then.  I can write the math logic of this it's just the comparing my values from my table to my constant which right now is `CurrentDate` and updating the values and writing the values to a certain table when the conditions meet.

Here's the code so far and there's a lot of mistakes trying to figure it out as well.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Run()
    'Declarations for grabbing data from the database for the VBA
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

    'Open connection to current Access database
    Set db = CurrentDb()

    'Declarations for variables to deal with dates
    Dim CurrentDate As Date
    Dim NextDateOut As Date
    Dim NextDateIn As Date
    Dim LastDateOut As Date
    Dim LastDateIn As Date

    'Setting a consistant value, technically not a constant value since there's no "const"
    CurrentDate = Date

    'Will take this out eventually
    MsgBox (CurrentDate)

    strSQL = "SELECT Next Date Out FROM Tapes Where Next Date Out = CurrentDate"
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    With rst
    If .RecorCount > 0 Then
        .MoveFirst
        .Edit
        !Next Date Out = (CurrentDate+20)
      .Update
    End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks in ADVANCE!!! I'm making progress but hitting walls on the way.  THANKS AGAIN!!!

Comment: There are two errors in the SQL statement: 1. you are not passing the value to the `where` condition; 2. The field name is not enclosed in square brackets: `strSQL = "select [Next Date Out] from tapes where [Next Date Out]=#" & CurrentDate & "#`. Notice that in Access SQL you need to enclose the dates between number signs, and `Date` values are sensitive to local configuration. I prefer to use `"select... where [Next Date Out]=" & CDbl(CurrentDate)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this directly with queries.

Let's split this problem into steps:

If `NextDateOut` (a field in your table) equals `currentDate` (a variable in your code), then:

1. You need to move all records for which the condition is true to a new table
2. For the records that remain in the table, you need to update `LastDateOut` to `currentDate`, `nextDateIn` to `currentDate + 10` and `nextDateOut` to `currentDate + 20`

If this is correct, you can try this:

```
dim strSQL as String
dim currentDate as Date
...
' Step 1: Copy the records to a new table '
strSQL = "insert into otherTable " & _
         "select * from tapes " & _
         "where [nextDateOut]=" & CDbl(currentDate)
doCmd.runSQL strSQL

' Step 2: Delete the records just copied '
strSQL = "delete from tapes where [nextDateOut]=" & CDbl(currentDate)
doCmd.runSQL strSQL

' Step 3: Update the dates in ALL the records remaining the "tapes" table '
strSQL = "update tapes " & _
         "set [lastDateOut]=" & CDbl(currentDate) & ", " & _
         "set [nextDateIn]=" & CDbl(currentDate + 10) & ", " & _
         "set [nextDateOut]=" & CDbl(currentDate + 20)
doCmd.runSQL strSQL
...
```

**Note:** I use `CDbl(currentDate)` to avoid problems with Date formats (MS Access stores dates as double values, with the integer part representing days and the decimal part representing fractions of days)

Hope this helps you

Comment: I have no idea if I'm doing this right so here's the link to my Access file.  There are no viruses and thanks in advance.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5sii3nf20ab349k/hBFc4APaXQ